# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable : ['conv2d_9/kernel:0', 'conv2d_9/bias:0', 'conv2d_10/kernel:0

Tags: keras, valueerror

I'm trying to train my keras model with an image dataset :

```
train_set=image_dataset_from_directory(      
     'C:/stage_data_inception/data collection/final dataset/train',                                 
     color_mode='rgb',        
     label_mode=None,
     batch_size=32,           
     image_size=(224,224),    
     shuffle=True,            
     seed=1,                  
     subset='validation',     
     alidation_split=0.2   
)
```

then I created a model :

```
input_1=Input(shape=(224,224,3))
Conv2D_1=Conv2D(filters=5,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='same',activation='relu')(input_1)
Conv2D_2=Conv2D(filters=3,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='valid',activation='relu')(Conv2D_1)
Conv2D_3=Conv2D(filters=3,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='valid',activation='relu')(Conv2D_2)
Conv2D_4=Conv2D(filters=3,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='valid',activation='relu')(Conv2D_3)
output=Dense(units=2,activation='softmax')(Conv2D_4)

model_1=tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_1,outputs=output)

model_1.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0005),
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.fit(train_set,epochs=10,verbose='auto')
```

this is the error I get :

```
raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d_9/kernel:0', 'conv2d_9/bias:0', 'conv2d_10/kernel:0', 'conv2d_10/bias:0', 'conv2d_11/kernel:0', 'conv2d_11/bias:0', 'conv2d_12/kernel:0', 'conv2d_12/bias:0', 'dense_5/kernel:0', 'dense_5/bias:0'].
```

I tried some solutions mentioned in similar problems, but I can resolve my problem

Comment: Probably `train_set` only returns `x` values, and you haven't provided any `y` values.

Comment: @Kaveh yes I figured out that this is the problem,thank you